# Аргументы методов класса

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qlistwidget

Есть код:

```
class ApplicationMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, ClientApp.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.cancel.clicked.connect(self.appExit)
        self.select.clicked.connect(self.selectModFolder)
        self.selectGame.clicked.connect(self.selectGameFolder)
        self.modsfile.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.moveMods(1))
    def moveMods(self, fromMethod):
        a = self.modsfile.currentRow()
        directory = self.urlMods.text()
        i = os.listdir(directory)
        i.reverse()
        if fromMethod == 1:
           #Что-то
```

Я хочу чтобы при выполнении вот этого:

```
self.modsfile.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.moveMods(0))
```

Вызывался метод с аргументом `fromMethod = 1`, но выскакивает ошибка, по причине количества aргументов. Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

> void QListWidget::**itemDoubleClicked**(QListWidgetItem ***item**) [signal]
>
> Этот сигнал испускается указанным элементом/item  при двойном щелчке кнопкой мыши на элементе/iteme в виджете.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemDoubleClicked

Т.е. этот сигнал по умолчанию передает **`item`**, если вы еще что-то хотите передать, то вам нужна `lambda`

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class ApplicationMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): #, ClientApp.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget) 
        
#        self.cancel.clicked.connect(self.appExit)
#        self.select.clicked.connect(self.selectModFolder)
#        self.selectGame.clicked.connect(self.selectGameFolder)
        
        self.modsfile = QListWidget()
        self.modsfile.addItems(['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4'])
        
        self.modsfile.itemDoubleClicked.connect(                           # +++
            lambda item, fromMethod=1: self.moveMods(item, fromMethod))    # +++
        
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.modsfile, 0, 0, 1, 1)  
        
    def moveMods(self, item, fromMethod):                                  # +++
        print(f'item.text = {item.text()}') #
    
        a = self.modsfile.currentRow()
#        directory = self.urlMods.text()
#        i = os.listdir(directory)
#        i.reverse()
        if fromMethod == 1:
           #Что-то
           print(f'fromMethod = {fromMethod} --> currentRow = {a}') #


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ApplicationMain()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я что-то совсем запутался,,, Я использовал лямбду как вы посоветовали, и мне в консоли почему-то возвращает вот это: `<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem object at 0x000001E6A4674A60>`  Я сталкивался с этой штукой, и всегда получалось её решить, но в этот раз - нет,

Comment: @cyp4ik31      видите что я печатаю `item.text()` , а вы что?

Comment: Я добавил  `item.text()`, и проблема исчезла! Спасибо огромное! Это решает проблему, но я не понимаю как это работает, именно объект `item`, могли бы вы меня просветить по этому поводу?

Comment: @cyp4ik31 я добавил некоторые пояснения в свой ответ, проверьте. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все понятно.